# Careers experience layout messed up in IE

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, internet-explorer

**Fixed** - Thanks guys!

Noticed that the public CV for careers has a different layout for Firefox and IE7.  In IE, I get the heading and tags on several lines:

[alt text http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/305/giantleapie.png](http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/305/giantleapie.png)

In Firefox I get the heading and tags on their own lines:

[image]

Of course, I prefer the firefox rendering, so I hope that is the intended layout.

- I'd appreciate it if others could take a peek and tell me what they see in their browser: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/adamdavis

-Adam

Comment: Everything looks fine in Chrome - formatting looks like the Firefox example above.

Comment: Wow I didn't know IE had embedded astronauts now... new quirks mode thing?

Comment: I totally didn't see the astronaut there before, but now I see why there was so much whitespace.  I take my request back, and now ask that firefox layout be fixed to allow for the careers astronaut.  What a way to launch a resume!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the records: Opera 10 works!

[alt text http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/5808/randomsopera.png](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/5808/randomsopera.png)

Comment: Dude, +1,000 for drawing of sydney opera house.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. It's not easy with a touchpad, I tell you!

Comment: Now that's a total win on three levels. Where be this super upvote button now?

Answer (score 4):

Browser bug. Looks good with IE8. Upgrade your browser.

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/8344/whousesie.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/8344/whousesie.png)

Comment: Company enforced browser.  Cannot upgrade, and you'll find many businesses in the same position.  Wish I could upgrade...

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't just insist that everyone visit your CV with a modern browser. Considering the target audience of the public CV page, I think it's important to have it correctly display in as many browsers as possible.

Comment: +1 for hand drawn circles and pogo stick guy.  Also for posting image of IE8 rendering.

Comment: ... circles? can't see any...

Comment: Sorry John, but as good as the pogo stick guy is, he can't quite compete with the opera house.

Comment: Maybe if you combined the two into one post with the pogo stick guy jumping over the opera house?  No, wait, opera is leaps and bounds better than IE, the analogy wouldn't work.  Back to the drawing board with you!

Comment: @Adam: Feel free to upvote both: my pogo guy and my opera house ;)

Comment: @John, oh I did, on all 57 of my accounts, too!  Unfortunately the anti-gaming algorithm Jeff implemented actually works.  _sigh_ ...